# how to replace image url get by wysiwyg editor in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: wysiwyg, media-images, magento2.3.5-p1

I got image like this from uploding image by wyusiwyg editor:

<img src="{{media url="http://example.com/media/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg"}}" alt="" />

but i want to replace this url like this:

and i want to do this using helper in custom module.

Please anyone can have idea then share with me.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: I want to get url like this :<img alt="" src="http://example.com/media/http://example.com/media/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg">